# How to fix 'Static page in sub-directory" issue in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have setup my Yii2 powered website but I will like to get some of my static pages in sub-directories and then display the name of the sub-directory in the url. For example, have in site/hotel/pacific.php and site/mini-rooms/standard.php and then access them using xyz.com/hotel/pacific and xyz.com/mini-rooms/standard.

I have tried to follow some examples online but I am not sure why the are not working. Some of the examples are also for yii and not yii2.
Here is what I did:

In the `SiteController.php`, I had created a static page before using the code below and I can visit it at`xyz.com/hotel/pacific`. But now I am moving it into a subdirectory `hotel`. It was formerly inside the views/site folder:

```
public function actionPacific()
{
    return $this->render('pacific');
}
```

I then created a folder name `pages` inside the `view` folder. Inside the `pages` folder, I created `hotel` folder and inside hotel folder I placed `pacific.php` file so I have `views/site/pages/hotel/pacific.php`

Also in the `SiteController.php`, I added this:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
        'page' => [
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ],
        'hotels' => [
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
            'basePath' => 'pages/hotels'
        ],          
    ];
}
```

I then configure my `config/web.php` by adding the code below:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing'=>false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',               
        ],
    ],
```

I got 404 error when I visit xyz.com/hotel/pacific.

How can I properly do this for both examples - `xyz.com/hotel/pacific` and `xyz.com/mini-rooms/standard`.

Comment: you map url on `controller/action` not folder structure,

Comment: I removed those codes but could not get it to work and left only the first line. I have updated the question. Can you take a look please?

Comment: I have gone through some documentation and it looks like the instruction I followed is different for yii2. For example, it seems `CViewAction` is not used again. Can you advise how to resolve this?

Comment: CViewAction seems for Yii1 ..   for Yii2 you should create a controller for miniRoom and add  the action you need

Comment: Thanks. But I am really a novice in Yii2. Just learning. Getting some help or tutorial will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create `HotelController.php` inside the `controller` folder and then create `hotel` folder under `views` folder. I then added `pacific.php` inside the hotel folder and add the action code inside `HotelController.php` as below.

```
public function actionPacific()
{
    return $this->render('pacific');
}
```

It works as I wanted although I am not sure if there are better alternatives. I removed the rules in the url manager as I did not need them now. I only had to just go to `mysite.com/hotel/pacific` to display the page. I can create as many page as I need inside the folder and just add their action code.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that you are mixing Yii `1` & `2` as `CWebView` is used in `Yii1` and not `Yii2`. So what you need is probably `yii\web\ViewAction`, which will represent a single action. There might be better answers someone else could suggest.

So if you have a directory.

- `views/site/hotel/pacific.php`
- `views/site/hotel/five-star.php`

And you want to access the `pacific.php` view by typing in the URL `xyz.com/hotel/pacific` and `five-star.php` with `xyz.com/hotel/five-star`.

Then you should configure them like below

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction'
        ],
        'pacific' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            'defaultView' => 'pacific',
            'viewPrefix' => 'hotel'
        ],
        'five-star' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ViewAction',
            'defaultView' => 'five-star',
            'viewPrefix' => 'hotel'
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null
        ]
    ];
}
```

and then update the urlManager like below

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing'=>false,
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            '<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            'hotel/<alias:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
        ]
],
```

Now if you type in the browser `xyz.com/hotel/pacific` or `xyz.com/hotel/five-star` it will show you the corresponding views.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I decided to create `HotelController.php` inside the `controller` folder and then create `hotel` folder under `views` folder. I then added the php view files inside the folder and add them inside `HotelController.php`. It works as I wanted although I am not sure if there are better alternatives.